# In Module Class method,is that possible to get the Class which mixedin that Module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Module A, and there are several Class need to Mixin it, there is a method should be wrote as Class Method of that Module, but this method need to get data from the Tables which match these Classes. It that realizable?

```
module Authenticate
  def password=(password)
    if password.present?
      generate_salt
      self.hashed_password = Authenticate.encrypt_password(password, salt)
    end
  end

  class << self
    def encrypt_password(password,salt)
      Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(password + salt)
    end
  end

  private
  def generate_salt
    self.salt = self.object_id.to_s + rand.to_s
  end

end


require 'authenticate_module'
class Administrator < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :password, :confirmation => true
  attr_accessor :password_confirmation
  attr_reader :password
  include Authenticate
end
```

This is that method:

```
def authenticate(name,password)
  if user = ???.find_by_name(name)
    if user.hashed_password == Authenticate.encrypt_password(password,user.salt)
      user
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Commenting as I'm not sure this is right.. Have you tried 'self.class' where your '???' is?

Comment: I think that may works in instance method,"puts self" in class method will be "Authenticate".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ActiveSupport::Concern to add class methods to every class that includes your module, then calling self in that method will return the class name.

It will be something like:

```
module Authenticate
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def authenticate(name, password)
      self.class # returns the name of the class that includes this module 
    end
  end
end


class User
  include Authenticate
end


# Now You can call
User.authenticate(name, password)
```

What ActiveSupport::Concern does is that whenever a class includes the module, it extends that class with the ClassMethods which here is equivalent to doing

```
class User
  include Authenticate
  extend Authenticate::ClassMethods
end
```

Comment: I don't believe you had to include this statement

extend Authenticate::ClassMethods

as ActiveSupport::Concern already does this for you!

Comment: @designwaves I was just explaining that using ActiveSupport::Concern is equivalent to those two commands. That's not part of the solution.

Comment: @Dipil  I know a lot has been going on with Concern recently with some changes so I thought I would throw it out there..no disrespect at all :)  It is a killer solution!!

Comment: I don't think this works. self.class would just return "Class"